# Import excel rows into MS-Access without header, VBA, TransferSpreadsheet method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

(Using MS Office Professional Plus 2016)

I adapted this sub procedure to import MS-Excel files/their first worksheet (called "Table") into an MS-Access database. The code navigates to the indicated folder and imports all .xls files in that folder. All .xls files have the same formatting. I'm using the **DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet** and a **Do While**.

**But**, the relevant data in the "Table" worksheets in the individual .xls files starts at line 29, the field names are in line 28.

My question is: Is there a way to only import the field names in line 28 and the data from line 29 to the last non-empty row - a way to include this in the Do While? Maybe with the Range option in the TransferSpreadsheet command, but I don't know how to express in the range "line x to last non-empty row".

```
Option Compare Database

Sub importfiles()

Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim strWorksheet As String, strTable As String
Dim strPath As String, strPathFile As String

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "E:\importfiles\"

' Replace worksheetname with the real name of the worksheet that is to be
' imported from each file
strWorksheet = "Table"

' Import the data from each workbook file in the folder
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      strTable = "tbl_" & Left(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, ".xls") - 1)

      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, _
            blnHasFieldNames, strWorksheet & "$"

      ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
      ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
      ' Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
MsgBox ("The sub was run.")

End Sub


Public Function runImport()

Call importfiles

End Function
```

```
(I slightly adapted this code from http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpWktFilesSepTbls)


EDIT:
[Type mismatch, see Max's answer][1]
 [Screenshot of excel file][2]

 [access table][3]

 [Compile error(see Max's answer)][4]


[for max][5]
[for max2][6]
[for max3][7]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZFnl.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjvKc.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzOXu.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHUTK.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slAeG.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6fNr.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFNqA.png
```

Comment: As far as i know transferspreadsheet imports only rows, that fit into the table. If you set the column-definition e.g. to "integer" for the first row and the excel is empty or text in the first 28 rows, does lines will not be imported. Try to find a column, where only rows 28:X fulfill a specific requirement, and set this in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did set the first column to integer, only the relevant data has an integer (number) in the first column of the worksheets. I get the error message: Run-time error '2391': Field 'F1' doesn't exist in the destination table 'Test1212'. Transferspreadsheet doesn't seem to care about this. Maybe there is some code that deletes the irrelevant header in the respective excel worksheet before every import?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the excel?

Comment: I added a link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a suggestion, that opens the excel file befor importing and defines the area to import. The minus 27 ist more or less guessed, please check in the excel for the area - it might be differend, just change the number.
The second change is that you define the area to import in the transferspreadsheet-command.

I hope this helps.
Max

```
Sub importfiles()

Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim strWorksheet As String, strTable As String
Dim strPath As String, strPathFile As String

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "E:\importfiles\"

' Replace worksheetname with the real name of the worksheet that is to be
' imported from each file
strWorksheet = "Table"

' Import the data from each workbook file in the folder
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile



''''alter the excel file
        Call alter_excel(strPathFile, strWorksheet)

      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
            acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTable, strPathFile, _
            blnHasFieldNames, "importarea"

      ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
      ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
      ' Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
MsgBox ("The sub was run.")

End Sub

Function alter_excel(file As String, table As String)
Dim oXL As New Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
     Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
     Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(file)
        oWB.Activate
        Sheets(table).Select
        Range("A30:D" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) + 5).Name = "importarea"

        oWB.Close True
        Set oWB = Nothing
        Set oXL = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" though (see the 3rd image in my post). What should I do?

Comment: you have to add a reference to the "Microsoft Excel Object library", maybe also the "Microsoft office object library"

Comment: Okay, I could've known that… Now I get: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. Maybe it should be "Dim oWS As Object" at the(beginning of the function) instead? The debugger marks "oWS.Select" yellow btw

Comment: No i think i forgot to set a worksheet... I have a closer look later...

Comment: After oWB.Activate as next line add set oWS = table ... I think that should do the job

Comment: I did edit the answer and tested in on my PC, seems to work!

Comment: I copied your answer into a new module in new database and got the type mismatch again. What do you have before Sub importfiles ()? Anything else I'm missing? I activated both the "Microsoft Excel Object library" and "Microsoft office object library". Is there some other setting that could cause this?

Comment: just did the same (new database), and works for me. Onla "Option Compare Database" ist inserted automatically, and Excel OBject LIbrary to be inserted. Where do you get the Type Mismatch?

Comment: I added another screenshot in my post ;) and the debugger marks the "Function alter_excel..." line yellow

Comment: sorry i do not find the new screenshot. The two screenshots i see are both containing "old" macro-parts... By the way: one of them has a german language error-message, are you german? I am from Austria, using german-language-office, which should not make a difference for vba.

Comment: I normally use office in english but this was on my laptop where it's in german. The screenshot with the german error message is the type mismatch error message ;) The link to the screenshot reads "Type mismatch, see Max's answer".

Comment: Ok in that screenshot you have a "old" code. Please try the answer as it is now - there is no "oWS" in there.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I didn't get a chance to answer… So I copied your answer, changed the path, and the MS excel and MS Office libraries are activated. It still doesn't work? I appended two screenshots ;)

Comment: sounds and looks like the name of the table is not correct - did you check that? By the way in the code there is a strWorksheet  and a strTable defined, I use the strTable ...

Comment: You mean the excel worksheet name, right? It's "Table" in the excel file I used for this test. I removed the strWorksheet, which didn't help. So if you use your exact answer with an excel file like this, it works?

Comment: Ok the code looked for a different name. I edited the code, have another try....

Comment: It seems like now a line like the one in the Do While "strTable = "tbl_" & Left(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, ".xls") - 1)" (you removed it) is missing. But even with it, it doesn't work. I added another screenshot, too (for max3). Sorry, my edit wasn't accepted without putting everything in code…

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the A1-style address from first to last cell in *Range* argument of [TransferSpreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) which includes headers as first row. And if rows are open-ended, enter in a very large end row where unused ranges interestingly are not imported!

```
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
   strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "myFinalTable", strPathFile, _
        True, strWorksheet & "$A29:D1000"

   strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Alternatively, you can directly query an Excel workbook in Access SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\myWorkbook.xlsx].[mySheet1$A29:D1000]
```

In fact, you can then run an append query from Excel source (possibly more efficient than `TransferSpreadsheet`).

```vb
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
   strPathFile = strPath & strFile

   sql = "INSERT INTO myFinalTable" _
         & " SELECT * " _
         & " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes;Database=" & strPathFile & "].[" & strWorksheet & "$A29:D1000]"

   Currentdb.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

   strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Do note: to adhere to database normalization, you should be migrating all data to **one**, long table and not separate spreadsheet tables that can run into the hundreds and more. Unlike Excel spreadsheets, Access tables have no row limit.